# flash download plugins unable to detect some flash videos

Tags: firefox, flash

Why are some plugins in Firefox are unable to detect and save flash files from websites?

I have installed many "flash downloader" plugins and on many websites they work and I can save the flash videos.

However, certain flash videos are not detected. Why? If you are able to download this [video](https://en-maktoob.screen.yahoo.com/latest-buzzfeed-videos/7-tricks-flawless-selfie-203952499.html?format=embed), please let me know which plugin do you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? Could be any number of reasons. The plugins (that need to parse web pages to extract links) need to be aware of the various tricks each site uses to hide the actual URLs and prevent users from downloading the videos. That's why when YouTube for example changes things at their end many of these video grabber plugins stop working till they're updated accordingly.

In this case since I don't use Flash I simply started playback, used Firefox's Inspect Element feature to see which WEBM was being served as an HTML5 video, then downloaded it directly:

https://ci-bf0b0bcf17-783b8f20.http.atlas.cdn.yimg.com/buzzfeed/4/0/53d9eeef-b3fd-4200-96aa-be7d39355e3b_8w_ENdgjDsRKkqQQCxBJFJKkz2ig1j5jJCF_9pHLdapsyObrWDTvS82zhHCvjfo-UbWp5f1nCWg-_12_0.webm?a=buzzfeed&b=7270&ib=sapi&m=video%2fwebm&mr=0&ns=ps&ps=ee007960-aacd-4dd0-a676-6491b7ca3a05&x=1429385348&s=23996fd59c3d4af11f37b1a3a329bf5e